# Selecting a row in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to select a row in a table I have created and need use the values. The issue I am having is I created it using doms in javascript and got the values from a stored procedure which then populates the table.

so i use a simple div with an id -

```
 <div id="Tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
```

to create the table and populate it i use an ajax call -

```
function GetcarData() {

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        price: slidval,
    }),
    url: "/index.aspx/GetData",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (object) {
        responseData(object);
    },
    complete: function (object) {

    },
    error: function (object) {
    }
});
}
function responseData(object) {
    var stringed = JSON.stringify(object.d)
    var arr = JSON.parse(stringed);
    var i;
    var out = "<table id='table' class='table table-striped'>";
    var rowHeader = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(out);
    out += "<td><font size='4'>Make</font></td>";
    out += "<td><font size='4'>Model</font></td>";
    out += "<td><font size='4'>Version</font></td>";
    out += "<td><font size='4'>Engine</font></td>";       
    out += "<td><font size='4'>(AV)Price new</font></td>";
    out += "<td><font size='4'>(Av)Price used</font></td>";
    out += "<td><font size='4'>Image</font></td>"

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].Make +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Model +
        "</td><td>" +
        "£" + arr[i].version +
        "</td><td>"+
          arr[i].Engine_size +           
        "</td><td>" +           
        "£" + arr[i].price_new +
        "</td><td>" +
         "£" + arr[i].price_used +
          "</td><td><img src="+arr[i].image_url+" width='150' height='100'>" +             
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("Tab1").innerHTML = out;

}
```

Now the issue I have is I cant seem to select a row.
I tried

```
("#table tr").click(function(){
alert("selected");
});
```

but that did not work.

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: Think about timing. When does `("#table tr").click(function(){ alert("selected");});` run? Does it run before your `responseData()` function is even called? Can you move the code that adds the click handler to the end of the `responseData()` function?

Comment: Excellent i knew it would be something trivial. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a set of elements that weren't in the DOM when page and were only added after initial `DOMContentLoaded`

To listen for events on elements that are dynamically added, removed via JavaScript DOM manipulations, you need to use slightly different `event` listener.

`$(document).on('%eventName%', '%selector%', function() { // do your stuff });`

Comment: Thank you that also worked. i really appreciate the help.